# Laravel AdminLTE template VUE error

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js

I wanted to add a bootstrap modal on my page, and I have included `jQuery` script in the head of the document. Here is the modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Delete {{$title}}?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete {{$body}}?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Yes</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>
```

I get an error on page load saying:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
...
...
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.


(found in <Root>)
```

And I don't know what is wrong since I used the same modal in my other project also and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of all the `<script>` tags in the template, put them outside of the template.

In this case you are using body as the template and you are putting scripts inside your template (body), and make sure you have a closing tag on your root element.

Comment: Can I easily get rid of Vue completely? I don't want it compiling anything